# very serious problem with hyperref in tex4ht after TL Oct. update

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

This seems to have happened after I updated TL 2020 on my Linux last night.

Now when building the same Latex file, with `url{}` in them, to HTML, using tex4ht, all the URL's are messed up and clicking on any gives page not found error.

No problem in the PDF compiled using lualatex.

What happens is that a URL such as

```
   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest?cta=question&id=234780
```

now shows, inside the generated HTML, as

```
<a class='url' 
  href='https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest cta=question&amp;id;=234780'>
<span class='rm-lmtt-12'>
```

Notice the difference near the end.

Here is a MWE and the command to generate the HTML

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\url{https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest?cta=question&id=234780}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo4.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

There was no such problem before this TL update. I looked at HTML page  compiled before OCT update, and the URL's there are correct. Here random one copied from the HTML page source compiled before this update

```
 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest?cta=question&#x0026;id=234240
```

Any one else sees this problem? Is there a workaround for it?

file list:

```
 *File List*
    book.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
    bk12.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyperref.sty    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi package
with kernel methods
 hluatex.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for luaTeX
   puenc.def    2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
atveryend.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery package
with kernel methods
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
l3backend-luatex.def    2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 nameref.sty    2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
```

Comment: I can confirm the problem. The command
`htlatex foo4 "xhtml, mathjax, htm, charset=utf-8" " -cmozhtf -utf8"`
(a space after `,` in the second argument for htlatex is necessary
only on Windows) seems to generate a correct result, so I suspect
that the problem is in make4ht utility.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Yes, `htlatex` does not have this problem. Actually just the command `htlatex foo4 "xhtml, mathjax, htm"` will produce the correct page. So only difference is `htlatex` vs, `make4ht` in the front, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already found that it happens only with `make4ht`. It uses the LuaXML library to clean up the generated HTML code. There seems to be a bug in the way how it parses the XML entities. It tries to convert named entities to Unicode characters. It mistaken `&id` as a named entity. Because it cannot find the mapping between `id` and any Unicode character, it returns the original entity. But here comes the issue, it appends the semicolon. So your url comes from:

```
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest?cta=question&id=234780
```

to

```
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest?cta=question&id;=234780
```

The `&` becomes `&amp;` later in the processing, but the spurious semicolon remains. The actual error is that `&id` is parsed as HTML entity. Only text between `&` and `;` should be parsed as entity. It is fixed in the development version of LuaXML, which should be uploaded to CTAN soon. In the meantime, you can place the updated file [luaxml-entities.lua](https://github.com/michal-h21/LuaXML/blob/master/luaxml-entities.lua) to the directory with your document.

It should produce the correct result:

```xml
<a class='url' href='https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest?cta=question&amp;id=234780'><span class='cmtt-12'>https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/landing/r/digest?cta=question&amp;id=234780</span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast fix. I verified it fixes the URL problem in the generated HTML.